# Accessing Facebook Graph API from unknown domains

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app that lets users place widgets on their websites where their visitors can optin with their email addresses (kinda similar to Leadpages).

Now I'd like to implement facebook optins but I'm having difficulties figuring out an elegant solution that will allow access to my FB app from unknown domains, so users can authorize my app and I can use the graph api to get their names and email addresses.

What kind of approach do you suggest? Currently, I'm handling this by opening a new popup with my domain's url that redirects users to the FB login page for my app and I handle everything else in that popup but it looks awful because the whole facebook.com is seen, not just the login part like in the JS SDK.

Thanks!